# Disable expand character spaces in Docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

Is there a chance to disable character spaces on a line that ends with SHIFT-RETURN in Docx4j ?
I am transforming html text into .docx file and i face this problem on justified aligned text. 
In MsWord there is special Layout Option, hope there is one in docx4j.

For Example:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for those who want to know how to solve this problem, i have found the way to solve it.

Here you go.

```
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        DocumentSettingsPart dsp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getDocumentSettingsPart();
        CTSettings settings = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTSettings();
        BooleanDefaultTrue val = new BooleanDefaultTrue();
        val.setVal(true);

        CTCompat compat = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTCompat();
        compat.setDoNotExpandShiftReturn(val);
        settings.setCompat(compat);
        dsp.setJaxbElement(settings);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(dsp);
```